# How to create multiple rank plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of 10 variables and 150 observation.

`ebi anago maguro ika uni sake tamago toro tekka.maki kappa.maki
   7     4      5   1   0    2      8    3          9          6
   1     4      5   7   2    0      8    6          9          3
   7     2      5   4   8    1      0    3          9          6
   4     7      5   1   2    0      3    8          6          9
   4     5      7   2   0    3      8    1          6          9
   4     5      7   2   0    3      1    8          6          9
   5     7      4   1   0    2      3    8          9          6
   5     4      1   6   7    2      0    8          3          9
   5     7      2   3   8    4      9    0          6          1
   1     7      2   0   8    3      5    4          6          9
   4     7      5   1   8    2      3    9          6          0
   7     5      0   4   2    3      8    6          1          9
   4     7      0   5   2    1      8    3          6          9
   4     5      7   0   3    1      2    6          8          9
   7     4      0   2   5    3      1    8          9          6
   7     5      4   0   2    3      8    1          6          9
   2     7      0   8   6    3      1    9          5          4
   7     2      5   4   3    0      8    1          6          9
   7     5      0   2   1    6      8    9          3          4
   7     4      5   0   3    1      2    8          6          9`

Every variable is the rank of the agent preference of sushi type and I'd like to create multiple plot in the same image like the one in the photo.

Any help?

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) about how to ask a good R question. To get you started, though, the picture you posted is using `ggplot2`'s `facet_wrap` to separate out plots...or it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

rank=read.csv('rank.csv')
melt=melt(rank, id.vars=NULL)
melt$value=factor(melt$value, c(9:0))
ggplot(melt, aes(value)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~variable, 5,5)
```

[image: facet wrap histogram]